# GIMP pythonfu get drawable from current image

Tags: gimp, gimpfu, python-fu

I am iterating over all open images. I want to apply threshold on each of them. Since the threshold plugin takes `drawable` as argument, the drawable should be changed every time the image is changed, at least that's what programatically makes sense. So, how do I get the drawable from the current image?

```
    for subimage in gimp.image_list():
        pdb.gimp_undo_push_group_start(subimage)
        pdb.gimp_drawable_set_image(drawable, subimage)
        pdb.plug_in_randomize_pick(image,drawable,rndm_pct, rndm_rcount, randomize, seed)
        spread_amount_x, spread_amount_y = 3, 3
        # pdb.plug_in_spread(subimage,drawable,spread_amount_x, spread_amount_y)
        pdb.plug_in_spread(subimage,drawable,spread_amount_x, spread_amount_y)
        pdb.plug_in_gauss_rle2(subimage,drawable,horizontal, vertical)
        # pdb.gimp_threshold(drawable, low_threshold, high_threshold)    
        pdb.gimp_undo_push_group_end(subimage)
```

Note that the commented out threshold would repeatedly apply the threshold on the selected image rather than all the images looped in. In order for me to do that, I have to switch to the drawable of the image in context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the images have a single layer, then either:

```
drawable=subimage.layers[0]
```

or

```
drawable=subimage.active_layer
```

If you have several layers, then you can use an index (the top layer is `layers[0]`, the bottom/background layer is `layers[-1]`), or you figure out the layer by other means, for instance be something like:

```
drawable=[d for d in image.layers if d.name=='Target'][0]
```

PS: Your script is likely going to run faster and use less RAM if you freeze the undo stack (or possibly even disable undo entirely) instead of doing undo-groups.